# An Error using get_reddit function of RedditExtractoR

Tags: r

For a text analysis class, I am supposed to scrape data using Reddit or Twitter. I am attempting to do this with the get_reddit function of RedditExtractoR in R. However, whenever I use the code:

`reditdata<-get_reddit(search_terms = "dating during covid", page_threshold = 1, cn_threshold = 10 )`

I get the following error message:

`Error in get_reddit(search_terms = "dating during COVID", page_threshold = 1,  :  could not find function "get_reddit"`

Can anyone help? I've updated the package, restarted R, etc.

Comment: It seems like none of the functions in RedditExtractoR work. I've updated R and restarted it!

Answer (score 1):

The functions you are trying to use are not available in version 3 or higher, you should instead use this:

```r
top_cats_urls <- find_thread_urls(subreddit="cats", sort_by="top")
threads_contents <- get_thread_content(top_cats_urls$url[1:2])
```

If you want to use the old functions, then you'll have to downgrade to 2.1.5 with `devtools::install_version("RedditExtractoR", version = "2.1.5", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

See [this GitHub page](https://github.com/ivan-rivera/RedditExtractoR) for more info.

Comment: @ IVR: This answer is AMAZING! Everyone needs to see it! I spent a day trying to figure this out and then found your answer! Thank you so much!!!!!